# Sys.ParameterCountException on extend of simple textbox control using microsoft js

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, javascript, jscript, microsoft-ajax

Here s my code trying to extend a textbox with microsoft ajax libary

On Page code is as follows :

[image: Code on the Default.aspx page]

Code in the .js file

[image: .Js file]

The error on debug is as follows

[image: Dubug error in microsoft js file]

what wrong am i doing in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error was in the constructor of the class which needed the element to be passed in the initializeBase method . Please see below .

[image]